# Convergence question about Lp norm when p tends to zero

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

I'm reading the book *Real and Complex Analysis* recently. And I encountered a question in the exercises of Chapter 3 that I can not solve for a long time. This question is about what the $L^p$ norm(not a norm when $p<1$) will become if we send p to zero.

Explicitly, Suppose $X$ is a measure space, $\mu$ is a probability measure on $X$. Define $$||f||_p = \left(\int_X|f|^pd\mu\right)^{1/p}$$for all $0<p<+\infty$ and complex measurable function $f$.

Assume that $||f||_r < \infty$ for some $r > 0$, and prove that $$\lim_{p\rightarrow0}||f||_p = \exp\left\{\int_X\log|f|d\mu\right\}$$if $\exp\{-\infty\}$ is defined to be $0$.

By using Jensen's Inequality and a conclusion that $|f|_r \leq |f|_s$ if $0<r<s<\infty$, I get half part of the conclusion:$$\lim_{p\rightarrow0}||f||_p \geq \exp\left\{\int_X\log|f|d\mu\right\}$$ Then it remains to prove $$\lim_{p\rightarrow0}||f||_p \leq \exp\left\{\int_X\log|f|d\mu\right\}$$ Or another form $$\lim_{p\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{p}\left(\int_X\log|f|^pd\mu - \log\int_X|f|^pd\mu\right) \geq 0$$ Then by inequality $\log(1+x) < x$, I only need to prove 
$$\lim_{p\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{p}\left(\int_X\log|f|^p-|f|^p + 1d\mu\right) \geq 0$$But the inequality seems to be wrong. Can this way work? Or are there any other solutions for this question?

Comment: Well you don't know the limit exists at that point, so I'm not sure why you think you get the half part. More importantly, you have used Jensen backwards. Jensen shows $\|f\|_p \ge \exp \int_X \ln |f|\,d\mu.$

Comment: Oh..Thank you for your comment, I made a mistake when using Jensen's Inequality. But the existence of limit is ensured by the inequality $|f|_r \leq |f|_s$ if $0<r<s\leq \infty$.